# How do I know that my rpm installation of a package was succesful?

Tags: rhel

I downloaded the rpm for dos2unix and installed (on RHEL 6, 64 bit) like this

```
[root@xilinx Downloads]# rpm -ivh dos2unix-5.3.3-5.ram0.98.src.rpm 
   1:dos2unix               warning: user mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: group mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: user mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: group mockbuild does not exist - using root
########################################### [100%]
[root@xilinx Downloads]#
```

But as can be seen I am getting these warnings. Why?

How do I know that my installation of dos2unix was succesful ?

**Update**

```
[root@xilinx Downloads]# rpm -ivh dos2unix-5.3.3-5.ram0.98.src.rpm
   1:dos2unix               warning: user mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: group mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: user mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: group mockbuild does not exist - using root
########################################### [100%]
[root@xilinx Downloads]# 
[root@xilinx Downloads]# 
[root@xilinx Downloads]# 
[root@xilinx Downloads]# 
[root@xilinx Downloads]# rpm -ql dos2unix
package dos2unix is not installed
[root@xilinx Downloads]#
```

I then tried

```
[root@xilinx acme]# yum install mock
Loaded plugins: refresh-packagekit, rhnplugin
There was an error parsing the RHN proxy settings.
RHN support will be disabled.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: InstallMedia. Please verify its path and try again
[root@xilinx acme]#
```

Comment: Did you mean to install the Source RPM?  Or did you want to install the binary RPM?  Or build the binary RPM from the source RPM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find out if the rpm's files have been installed:

```
rpm -ql dos2unix
```

Regarding your installation, it looks good, the rpm expects a group (mockbuild) and a user that you do not have. Should be fixed by the rpm responsible, but these are warnings only and your installation most probably worked fine.

Comment: see above updated:  says package dos2unix is not installed

Comment: not sure... the package name may be dos2unix-5.3.3-5. Can you do rpm -qa|grep dos2unix

Answer (score 13):

Any time you install an RPM you can check if it's installed using RPM's query switch. You can find our 2 useful pieces of info about an installed package.

However before I get into all that notice the name of the `.rpm` you installed.

```
dos2unix-5.3.3-5.ram0.98.src.rpm
```

#### Binary RPMS vs. Source RPMs

This is a source RPM, which isn't built software (binary), rather this is a package that you can use to rebuild/recompile the normal `.rpm` file from.  You typically do this using the `rpmbuild` command:

```
$ rpmbuild --rebuild dos2unix-5.3.3-5.ram0.98.src.rpm
```

You can also tell the difference if you list the contents of the package prior to installing it.

```
$ rpm -qpl dos2unix-5.3.3-5.ram0.98.src.rpm
dos2unix-5.3.3.tar.gz
dos2unix.spec
```

Notice this `.rpm` includes a `.spec` file? That's the "recipe" file for how to compile and install the dos2unix software which is also included in the file, `dos2unix-5.3.3.tar.gz`.

You can read more about source RPMs (aka. src.rpm or .srpm) files on the rpm.org website in this article titled: [Source Package Files and How To Use Them](http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-miscellania-srpms.html).

So instead you should be installing a package named like this if you truly want to install dos2unix:

- dos2unix-5.3.3-5.ram0.98.i386.rpm
- dos2unix-5.3.3-5.ram0.98.x86_64.rpm
- dos2unix-5.3.3-5.ram0.98.i686.rpm
- dos2unix-5.3.3-5.ram0.98.noarch.rpm

**NOTE:** The rest of this post shows how you'd find binary RPM's such as these install on your system.

---

#### rpm -qi <...pkg name..>

This will give you standard information about a given package. Version, where it was built, when it was built etc.

```
$ rpm -qi dos2unix
Name        : dos2unix
Version     : 6.0.3
Release     : 2.fc19
Architecture: x86_64
Install Date: Sat 07 Dec 2013 09:02:59 PM EST
Group       : Applications/Text
Size        : 184775
License     : BSD
Signature   : RSA/SHA256, Thu 14 Mar 2013 05:25:00 AM EDT, Key ID 07477e65fb4b18e6
Source RPM  : dos2unix-6.0.3-2.fc19.src.rpm
Build Date  : Fri 22 Feb 2013 10:50:05 AM EST
Build Host  : buildvm-20.phx2.fedoraproject.org
Relocations : (not relocatable)
Packager    : Fedora Project
Vendor      : Fedora Project
URL         : http://waterlan.home.xs4all.nl/dos2unix.html
Summary     : Text file format converters
Description :
Convert text files with DOS or Mac line endings to Unix line endings and
vice versa.
```

#### rpm -ql <..pkg name..>

You can get the contents of an RPM using the `rpm -ql <..pkg name..>`.

```
$ rpm -ql dos2unix
/usr/bin/dos2unix
/usr/bin/mac2unix
/usr/bin/unix2dos
/usr/bin/unix2mac
/usr/share/doc/dos2unix-6.0.3
/usr/share/doc/dos2unix-6.0.3/COPYING.txt
/usr/share/doc/dos2unix-6.0.3/ChangeLog.txt
...
```

#### Verifying a package installation

There is a lesser though still useful switch which will allow you to verify the installation of a package. This switch will qualify the files on disk to make sure that their permissions are set correctly, the same as when it was installed, as well as perform a checksum (MD5SUM) of each file to make sure it hasn't been tampered with or changed.

```
$ rpm -V -v dos2unix
.........    /usr/bin/dos2unix
.........    /usr/bin/mac2unix
.........    /usr/bin/unix2dos
.........    /usr/bin/unix2mac
.........    /usr/share/doc/dos2unix-6.0.3
.........  d /usr/share/doc/dos2unix-6.0.3/COPYING.txt
.........  d /usr/share/doc/dos2unix-6.0.3/ChangeLog.txt
.........  d /usr/share/doc/dos2unix-6.0.3/NEWS.txt
...
```

You should only see dots in the left column. If you see letters such as `S` or `M` then you know the size or permissions are inconsistent.

*excerpt from rpm man page*

```
   S file Size differs
   M Mode differs (includes permissions and file type)
   5 digest (formerly MD5 sum) differs
   D Device major/minor number mismatch
   L readLink(2) path mismatch
   U User ownership differs
   G Group ownership differs
   T mTime differs
   P caPabilities differ
```

Answer (score 4):

The ‘mock’ module is responsible to build the source RPMs (SRPMs) under a chroot environment and uses the ‘mockbuild’ user. If the mockbuild user does not exist while installing the source RPM, you will receive the ‘Warning: user mockbuild does not exist. using root‘ error message. In order to fix the warning message, install the ‘mock’ module:

```
# yum install mock
```

and create the ‘mockbuild’ user

```
# useradd -s /sbin/nologin mockbuild
```

Once done, you should be able to install the required tool under the mockbuild user.

[from this source](http://linuxhostingsupport.net/blog/warning-user-mockbuild-does-not-exist-using-root)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install a *source* `rpm` you need first to build it:

```
# rpmbuild --rebuild dos2unix-5.3.3-5.ram0.98.src.rpm
```

The `mock` package is not required to do this, so you can ignore the warnings:

```
warning: user mockbuild does not exist - using root
warning: group mockbuild does not exist - using root
```

The `rpmbuild` will create a *binary* `rpm`. The location may vary, e.g. `/usr/src/redhat/RPMS/` or `~/rpmbuild/RPMS` (the output of `rpmbuild` should help with this). The RPM will be in a subdirectory representing your architecture (e.g. `x86_64/`). You can install normally this `rpm`:

```
# rpm -Uvh /usr/src/redhat/RPMS/x86_64/dos2unix-5.3.3-5.x86_64.rpm
```

If there were no errors, you should have the package installed:

```
# rpm -q dos2unix
dos2unix-5.3.3-5
```